# ClientScriptManager Redirects to Default page but code still executes

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i have a code

```
ClientScriptManager CSM = Page.ClientScript;
string strconfirm = "<script>if(!window.confirm('No Yesterday Date!! Continue?')){window.location.href='Default.aspx'}</script>";
CSM.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Confirm", strconfirm, false);
```

The problem is when user click the cancel button code redirects to Default.aspx but the code after the script also executes. i want to prevent the code to be executed when user clicks Cancel

Comment: Can you provide more code? Are you using a Popup Modal? Where did you place the code above, in which method?

Comment: So basically you want to redirect when user click ok. right?

Comment: I placed the code in a Save Button Click Event of ASP.Net form. It checks the user input date and if it is not equal to Yesterday date then asks for confirmation with OK and Cancel buttons. Its okay when user clicks OK button but When user click Cancel it executes the rest of code line and then redirects. I want to skip the rest of code and redirect to Default.aspx